# setwd() from a batch file in R

Tags: r, batch-file, command-line, automation

I want to run a R script from a batch file to automate the same process and want to set working directory in the batch file.

**R script**

```
files <- list.files(pattern=*.csv", full.names=TRUE, 
recursive=FALSE)

lapply(files, function(x) {

  df <- read.csv(x, header = TRUE, sep = ",")

 inds <- which(df$pc_no == "DELL")
 df[inds - 1, c("event_rep", "loc_id")] <- df[inds, c("pc_no", "cust_id")]
 df1 <- df[-inds, ]

 write.csv(df1, paste0('cleaned_', x), row.names = FALSE)

}
```

**BATCH FILE**

```
"C:\R\R-3.5.1\bin\i386\R.exe" CMD BATCH 
"C:\folder\myscript.R" -e setwd("C:\Documents") 
"C:\folder\test.Rout"
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Rscript allows you to pass either a file path to a script **or** a command via the "-e" option. You cannot pass both. You would need to set the working directory in the actual script itself somewhere. You can pass arguments to your command with `commandArgs()` or something similar if you like.

Comment: `commandArgs()` is how I have solved this issue in the past

Comment: @MrFlick I added my script above. Where can I use commandArgs() in the script? After that how to change the batch file?

Comment: @duckmayr Can you explain in a bit more detail?

Comment: @KadirŞenkaya See the answer I just added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `commandArgs()` with `Rscript` to easily get the behavior you desire. Consider the following R script which I have called `so-answer.R`:

```
# First get the argument giving the desired working directory:
wd <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
# Then check if we can correctly set the working directory:
setwd(wd)
getwd()
```

Then we can run it from the command line, passing as an argument the directory we want:

```
duckmayr@duckmayr-laptop:~$ Rscript so-answer.R Documents
[1] "/home/duckmayr/Documents"
```

A good, accessible explanation of `commandArgs()` can be found at [this blog post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/passing-arguments-to-an-r-script-from-command-lines/).

If you're really dead set on using `R CMD BATCH`, take a look at [this blog post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/including-arguments-in-r-cmd-batch-mode/) and try something like the following:

```
# First get the argument giving the desired working directory:
eval(parse(text = commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)[1]))
# Then check if we can correctly set the working directory:
setwd(wd)
getwd()
```

that you can run from the command line like

```
duckmayr@duckmayr-laptop:~$ R CMD BATCH '--args wd="Documents"' so-answer.R so-answer.Rout
```

which results in this output

```
duckmayr@duckmayr-laptop:~$ cat so-answer.Rout

R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> # First get the argument giving the desired working directory:
> eval(parse(text = commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)[1]))
> # Then check if we can correctly set the working directory:
> setwd(wd)
> getwd()
[1] "/home/duckmayr/Documents"
> 
> proc.time()
   user  system elapsed 
  0.478   0.052   0.495
```

Answer (score 1):

In Windows:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.1\bin\i386\Rscript.exe" -e "setwd('C:\\Users\\saeid\\Documents');source('myscript.R')" > "C:\Users\saeid\Documents\test.Rout"
```

and myscript.R is:

```
print(getwd())
```

test.Rout content:

```
[1] "C:/Users/saeid/Documents"
```